# Can I Access wp-includes Without Connecting to FTP?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site and have not been given FTP access. I can get to most of what I need via the Wordpress > Editor feature, but I need to get to the `wp-includes/general-template.php` - is this possible without connecting to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these ftp file plugin that lets u edit stuff from browser or download?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/ftp